# SQl Query Executor registered but still getting error in Netbeans and iReport

Tags: mysql, sql, netbeans, jasper-reports, ireport

I am using *NetBeans* and *iReport*. SQL query executor is registered in *iReport* options but still when i try to generate the report through my app (which i created on *Java*), it gives me SAXexception that no query executor factory is registered for SQL language.

What should i do now?